# Can a sentence starting with "I think" be used to state a fact?

Tags: meaning-in-context

If I say, "I think I will take another portion of lasagna", does that mean I am going to take another portion of lasagna?

Similarly, can the following sentence be used to state that Verona is my favorite city?

> I think Verona is my favorite city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I hear someone say "I think" at the beginning of a sentence, I'm prepared to understand that the following information is either a statement of belief or a statement indicating uncertainty. For example:

> I think God exists.

This is a statement of belief and can be replaced with *I believe in God*.

> I think Verona is my favorite city.

This is a statement of uncertainty, not a statement of fact. Were it a statement of fact, a native Anglophone would normally say *Verona is my favorite city*.

If you say, on the other hand:

> I think I will take another portion of lasagna.

You are either stating a fact (*I will have some more lasagna*) or asking for permission (*I want more lasagna. Is it okay if I take another piece?*).

Context and intention, in so far as it can be determined, decide whether "I think" can precede a statement of fact.

Comment: Could "I think Verona is my favorite city." be used as another way to mean "So far, Verona is my favorite city"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That's how I understand "I think Verona is my favorite city": **Right now it's my favorite city, but tomorrow Rome might be my favorite city**.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I think so; yes, you can. When using _"I think..."_ to express an opinion, it's also a way of removing dogmatism from your statement. Maybe you're a little hesitant declaring, "Verona is my favorite city," because it's hard to pick just one favorite. Maybe there are five or six cities you like a lot, and it's hard to pick just one. In cases like that, _"I think..."_ sort of "softens" the assertion, if that makes sense.

Comment: +1 for @J.R.'s observation that _"I think"_ is used to soften assertions.  This is good to be aware of in public speaking.   _"I think"_, used too often, can give the impression that your conclusions are tentative. Saying _"I think sales will improve if we paint the cows blue"_ allows you to back out, or caveat your answer.  _"....I could be wrong, though - who knows what color cows people want these days?"_  If you are 100% sure you are correct, consider a stronger form: _"Sales will improve if we paint the cows blue.  Get your brushes, everyone."_